# Convert a user Input date time to firestore timestamp value

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, momentjs

I have a user input date string and I want to save it with in a timestamp field in firestore.
when I am using `Timestamp.fromDate(new Date('2023-03-03 18:06:00'))` it is saving in a timestamp field but time is coming wrong(3/3/23, 11:36 PM).
When I am using `new Date('2023-03-03 18:06:00').toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'Asia/Calcutta' });` and then using `Timestamp.fromDate()`
It is throwing an error.
My input is "2023-03-03 18:06:00"
That should be stored in a field with value 3/3/23, 06:06 PM in firestore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase console uses **the timezone configuration of your computer** to display the Timestamp value in your local time but the value is stored in UTC in Firestore.

So what you describe in your question is the correct situation, since the 'Asia/Calcutta' timeZone is 5 hours and 30 minutes ahead of UTC Time. You see 3/3/23, 11:36 PM in the Firebase console which corresponds to the value you saved in Firestore, i.e. 3/3/2023, 06:06 PM.

Conclusion: In your app, you need to format the date according to your users requirements, knowing that in Firestore the Timestamp is in UTC.